# The "mode" of sum of dependent random variables

Tags: mode

Is there some study on finding the mode of sum of dependent random variales?
Or give some bounded zone for the mode?
Million thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 1):

[The mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29) is bounded within 3^(1/2) multiple of the standard deviation around the mean for unimodal continuous distributions.